# Write to console when stdin/stderr/stdout redirected in Activestate Perl

Tags: perl, winapi, console, windows-console, activestate

I have the following code to write to the Windows command console:

```
use Win32::Console;
my $console = new Win32::Console(Win32::Console::STD_ERROR_HANDLE());
my $defaultAttribute = $console->Attr();
my $defaultFG = ($defaultAttribute & 0x0F);
my $defaultBG = ($defaultAttribute & 0xF0);
$console->Attr($defaultBG | $Win32::Console::FG_LIGHTGREEN);
$console->Write("blah blah");
$console->Attr($defaultAttribute);
```

This code fails if the user redirects STDERR when invoking my script:

```
perl myscript.pl 2> foo
```

How can I obtain a handle to the Win32 console the process is attached to without reference to one of the standard handles so that it doesn't matter what redirections the user makes?

The effect I want is to be able to write a message on the console immediately following normal program output regardless of any redirection in a similar way to the bash builtin `time` command.  Essentially, similar to opening and writing to `/dev/tty` in Unix.

I've tried `my $console = new Win32::Console()` to allocate a new console followed by `$console->Display()` but this does completely the wrong thing.

Comment: There usually **is** a good reason to say 2>blubb. I hate it when programs demand attention when I told them to be silent.

Comment: @Ingo: Fair point but I'm not going to modify the requirements for a program I write for myself to suit you.  :-)

Comment: You made my day! You mean, just in case you accidentaly type 2>NUL ....

Comment: @Ingo: No. My command is like bash's `time` and I want to use it like: `cd this && mytime mvn ... >> ..\x 2>&1 && cd ..\that && mytime mvn ... >> ..\x 2>&1` with compile output in x and timings on screen. Plus it fills in what seemed to me to be a gap between what Win32::Console allows and what is possible with the Windows API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After asking this question, I delved a bit deeper and was able to solve it by using a nasty hack:

```
use Win32API::File qw(createFile);
use Win32::Console;

my $handle = createFile('CONOUT$', 'rwke') or die "conout\$: $^E\n";
# my $console = new Win32::Console($handle) or die "new console: $^E\n";
my $console = bless {handle => $handle}, 'Win32::Console';
```

I looked at the code for the `new()` function inside `Win32::Console` and saw that it just creates a hash containing the handle to a console. If the parameter specifies stdin/stdout/stderr, it just retrieves the associated handle otherwise it creates a new console screen buffer and uses the handle for that.

So I just manually created the `Win32::Console` object containing a handle to the console returned by CreateFile.

So now `perl myscript.pl > nul 2> nul < nul` will write `blah blah` on the screen immediately below the command line.

I'll accept a better answer if someone comes up with one.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [AllocConsole()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) docs (C++ docs, but the concepts are the same):

"A process can be associated with only one console, so the AllocConsole function fails if the calling process already has a console. A process can use the FreeConsole function to detach itself from its current console, then it can call AllocConsole to create a new console or AttachConsole to attach to another console."

Since your console is already redirected it doesn't look like there's anything you can do about it; even if you detach the console and allocate a new one, the new console inherits the redirection. In C++ you would use the [SetStdHandle()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686244%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API to force the standard handles to point to a different file or device, but I can't find any Perl equivalent of that.

Comment: Redirecting the standard handles does not free the console. `CreateFile('conout$')` will retrieve the handle to the allocated console but there's no direct way of using this in Perl's Win32::Console module.

Comment: Failing to see where I said that redirecting would free the console... In any case your comment about having no direct way to change it was my point. Also I would expect CreateFile on conout$ to also get you a handle to the redirected output.